# Find closest point from point outside polygon mesh to polygon mesh

Tags: c++, geometry, computational-geometry, cgal

I have a polygon mesh defining a valid inner region and a point outside of this polygon mesh. From this point i want to find the closest point on the surface on my polygon mesh.

I have no background in computational geometry and don't know the buzzwords. How can i achieve this using cgal or any other library in C++?

Comment: What is a *concave* 3D polygon ?

Comment: Sorry, i guess my wording is not on point. With the term _concave_ i wanted to stress that my polygon is not some "well-behaved" ball shape. My polygon is constructed from a point cloud, similar to [here](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Manual/tuto_reconstruction.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have a look at the [Location Functions](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Polygon_mesh_processing/group__PMP__locate__grp.html) in CGAL.